# Define a function that writes in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having some problems on defining a function that the only purpose is to write a file.

```
from sys import argv

script, file_user = argv

def print_all(rw):                                  # We create a define function that prints the file
    print(rw.read())

def rewind(rw):                                     # We create a define function that starts from the beginning of the file
    rw.seek(0)

def escri(rw):                                      # We create a define function that writes wathever the user wants
    rw.write()

def count(line_count, rw):                          # we create a define function that counts and reads a line
    print(line_count, rw.readline())

user = open(file_user, 'w')                         # we open the file

print("Now we open the file")

line = input('Write wathever you want: ')           # we ask the user for the input
line1 = input('Write wathever you want: ')
line2 = input('Write wathever you want: ')


escri(line)
escri("\n")
escri(line1)                                   # we write it in the file
escri("\n")
escri(line2)
escri("\n")

print('Writed...')

rewind(user)                                        # we rewind the file back to the beginning

print('We are in the beginning of file... start counting...')

current_line = 1
count(current_line, user)

current_line += 1
count(current_line, user)

current_line += 1
count(current_line, user)
```

Now the error I get is AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'.

I tried by not defining it as a function and just user.write() but when I do that it doesn't count all the lines specified

Comment: `user` is your file object, and `line` is a string. When you call `escri(line)` you're not making use of your file object; you're just passing a string to the function and calling `write()` on the string, as if the string will know what you're trying to write it to.

Comment: How do I call the function and write it?

Comment: Your function `escri` takes an argument that is a file object in your head, but in reality is a string you pass in. You just need to define your functions so that they take two args: the file object, and the string you want to read/write, and modify the function bodies accordingly.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: I read it, but I still can't solve it

Answer (score 0):

The value being passed to the function escri is a string. You should change in the function body. Open the file the in the function, example:

`def escri(user, line): user.write(line)`

So you pass the lineyou want to write and keep the user as the file you already opened.

I think this should work, I'm on my phone I can't test it.

Comment: It says an error, but basically if I put user.write(line) it doesnt write the other lines either

Comment: You have to call the `escri` def each time you want to write a line, and pass the line you want to write in the parameter